# Blacklist SQL Database. Not working Discord.py

Tags: python, database, sqlite, discord, discord.py

```py
db = sqlite3.connect("BlacklistedUsers.db")
c = db.cursor()
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "BlacklistedUser_IDs" (
    "User_IDs"  INTEGER,
    "Reason"    TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("User_IDs")
);''')

def owner_ID(ctx):
    return ctx.author.id == 738332946934661132

def not_allowed(ctx):
    member = ctx.discord.member.id
    c.execute("SELECT `User_IDs` FROM `BlacklistedUser_IDs` WHERE `User_IDs`=%s", (member))
    UserID = cursor.fetchall()
    if ctx.author.id not in UserID:
        print(UserID)
        return True
    else:
        return False

@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CheckFailure):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="", description="", colour=discord.Color.red())
        embed.set_author(name="BlackListed!")
        embed.add_field(name="Sorry", value=f"{ctx.author} It looks like you've been Blacklisted! for {Reason}", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="If you would like to Appeal Or think this might have been a mistake Message", value="@L Y N X", inline=False)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@bot.command()
@commands.check(owner_ID)
async def blacklist(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    c.execute("INSERT INTO `BlacklistedUser_IDs`(User_IDs, Reason) VALUES(%s, %s)", (member.id, reason))
    db.commit()
    embed = discord.Embed(title="", description="", colour=discord.Color.red())
    embed.set_author(name="Blacklisted!")
    embed.add_field(name="Success", value=f"{member.name}#{member.discriminator} -- {member.id} Has been Blacklisted from Using commands!")
    embed.add_field(name="Reason : ", value=f"{reason}")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@bot.command()
@commands.check(owner_ID)
async def unblacklist(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    c.execute("DELETE FROM BlacklistedUser_IDs WHERE User_IDs =%s AND Reason=%s;", (member.id, reason))
    db.commit()
    embed = discord.Embed(title="", description="", colour=discord.Color.red())
    embed.set_author(name="Unblacklisted!")
    embed.add_field(name="Success", value=f"{member.name}#{member.discriminator} -- {member.id} Has been Unblacklisted from Using commands!")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

When trying to run this Command it wont Run Fullstop.. It'll run anything above the SQL but when it comes to the SQL it wont run, Both for Blacklist and Unblacklist?? everything looks correct so i'm confused as to what is wrong..

any solutions // Problem fixes?

Comment: What do you mean by "it won't run"? Is there an error? Does the script stall? Please put more details if you can

Comment: I run the command, But it Stalls and wont run ANYTHING within in the command's code, anything above ``c.execute`` will run, but the ``c.execute`` seem's to 1) Break the whole code, 2) Doesn't Work, it wont Put anything into the database, or anything and it's confusing to me as to why because it looks correct but SQL seems to break that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problem in your code sample:

- The way you insert data is wrong
- `db` and `c` aren't defined
- Your `commands.check()` decorator seems to be wrong

Let's say your table name is `table` and it has two rows nammed `row_1` and `row_2`. If you want to insert two values, for instance `var_1` and `var_2` here's how you do it:

```py
with sqlite3.connect('database.db') as connection:
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO table(row_1, row_2) VALUES(?, ?)', (var_1, var_2))
    connection.commit()
```

Your second error might come from `@commands.check(owner_ID)`. If it's just an ID, you're using [`commands.check()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20check#discord.ext.commands.check) the wrong way. In this case, if your goal is to make this command only accessible for the bot creator, you can use [`@commands.is_owner()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=is_owner#discord.ext.commands.is_owner):

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def blacklist(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    ...
```

With all those changes, your code would look like this:

```py
from sqlite3 import connect

@bot.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def blacklist(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    with connect('BlacklistedUsers.db') as conn:
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("INSERT INTO BlacklistedUser_IDs(User_IDs, Reason) VALUES(?, ?)", (member.id, reason))
        conn.commit()

    embed = discord.Embed(colour=discord.Color.red())
    embed.set_author(name="Blacklisted!")
    embed.add_field(name="Success", value=f"{member.name}#{member.discriminator} -- {member.id} Has been Blacklisted from Using commands!")
    embed.add_field(name="Reason :", value=f"{reason}")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

For your `is_allowed()` function : note that I changes `ctx` to `member_id` since you only need the member ID. When you call this function, you'll just have to pass the member id (eg. `is_allower(ctx.member.id)`) :

```py
def not_allowed(member_id):
    with connect('BlacklistedUsers.db') as conn:
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT User_IDs FROM BlacklistedUser_IDs WHERE User_IDs=?", (member,))
    UserIDs = cursor.fetchall()
    return False if member_id in UserIDs else True
```

Comment: I Have the definitions up top, lemme grab them really quick,

Comment: I've Updated the Source Question^

Comment: The code sample that I gave should work. You should create a connector and a cursor only when you need it tho. Also, if 738332946934661132 is your ID, you don't need that `commands.check()`, you can simply use `commands.is_owner()`

Comment: I'm Very new to SQL lmao, so the Select and delete is the main problem i'm having now,

Comment: What you need to do : remove the `ower_ID` function / replace the decorator to `@commands.is_owner()` / replace your `blacklist` function with the code I gave you. Since your database is already generated, you can delete all the sqlite part at the beginning of your code :) You'll also have to adapt the sqlite code sample I gave in your `not_allowed` function

Comment: ahh,,, annoying Question-- How would i do that? haha, i've done it for the unblacklist but its not working..
i've removed owner_id and changed it to @commands.is_owner()

Comment: I've edited my answer. For further questions, please make some researchs before.

Comment: Have you got a discord i could message you on by chance?

Comment: If your problem was solved, could you please accept this answer ?

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble understanding what i 1) need todo and 2) how to get this to work, the Blacklist code runs, but the unblacklist and the check has me confused,